# Extra width on <h1> tag due to text wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have an  element. When the screen width is small, I see that there is some automatic wrapping that is going on without having to apply any css. However, when the wrapping takes place, the actual <h1> element's width becomes greater than it is supposed to be with extra white space.

When there is no wrapping, the <h1>'s width stretches out just as far as the text:
[image: No word wrapping]

But when there is wrapping, there is extra width that I want to remove:
[image: Word wrapping]

How would I go about removing this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share some HTML + CSS that reproduce the problem ([as text, not as a screen shot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)) -- i.e., a [mcve].  See also [ask] for additional tips for writing questions that are more likely to attract an answer.

Comment: you cannot remove it